# Can we deform continuously $\text{id}:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ into the constant map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Can we deform continuously $\text{id}:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y) $, into the constant map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (where I guess $(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)\,\,$)?$

I am trying to understand why the above is true. I know that there exists such map and I am trying to understand why. From what I know, any contractible space has a trivial fundamental group. Now, I do not know if the opposite is true, but if it is then since $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is trivial then the space is contractible and we can choose to contract at the point $(0,0)$.

Also, we know that a deformation retraction $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies the following: $F(\vec{x},0)=\vec{x}=(x,y)$, $F(\vec{x},1)\in (0,0)$ and $F(\vec{0},1)=(0,0)$. This satisfies what I want but I cannot find what this $F$ is (and it must be continuous of course!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $F(x,t)=(1-t)x$. Note that it is not true that a space is necessarily contractible if it has trivial fundamental group. For example, any sphere of dimension greater than 1 has trivial fundamental group and is not contractible.

Comment: Yes, of course, I was looking for something more complex. As for your second point, can you not take a sphere and shrink it to a point?

Comment: You can shrink it to a point in the space it is embedded in, but there's no way to shrink it to a point and have everything always remain entirely within the sphere. (Note that sphere here means the set of points of distance 1 from the origin).

Comment: But it is effectively a point, isnt it? I do not really understand what you mean because when I say point I mean for example in the case of $S^2$, $(0,0)$. If you shrink a sphere to this point, I naively think, this is a deformation retraction.. :/ where is my confusion?

Comment: $(0,0)$ is not inside $S^2$. Perhaps you are thinking of the ball containing all points of distance less than or equal to 1 from the origin? If not, note that a deformation retraction of a sphere must have all stages entirely contained within the sphere. It is a function whose domain is $S^2\times [0,1]$ and whose codomain is $S^2$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking of the unit ball. Then, to what space does the sphere retract? I understand that the ball then retracts into a point, but the sphere?

Comment: The sphere does not deformation retract onto any proper subspace.